# TouchesBegan not triggering on presented SKScene

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have an SKScene and I present another scene in it. Here is the code for presentation:

```
[self.view presentScene:[[LoseScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size] transition:[SKTransition crossFadeWithDuration:1.5]];
```

Here is my init code for lose scene:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

// code omitted
    }
    return self;
}
```

Problem is that this method in LoseScene is never getting called:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Comment: have you tried: self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Yes, I did, it doesn't help.

Comment: are there any gesture recognizers that may "eat" touches? Any other UIViews in front of the sk view?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the problem was? I am having the same issue. Very simple scene is loaded but none of the touch methods are called.

Comment: @Made2k nope. I made a new Xcode project and it seemed to work from there.

Comment: @Dvole I actually found the problem. I was presenting a scene fine, just like you, however when I was calling presentScene it kept getting called. There's some weird behavior when you keep presenting a scene. Essentially I set a flag so it would only trigger once and that solved the issue for me. Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you got it working but if anyone else is running into this issue I figured out what can cause weird behavior. A lot of issues can arise if you happen to call presentScene too many times. This can happen if presentScene is in the update method.

```
- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {
    [self.view presentScene:myScene transition: reveal];
}
```

The view is constantly presenting the scene which will cause all sorts of things to break. Make sure this only gets called once when you want to present the scene and things should work fine. A simple flag would do.

```
- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {
    if(_gameOver) {
        [self.view presentScene:myScene transition: reveal];
        _gameOver = NO;
    }
}
```